# PySpark: StructField(..., ..., False) always returns `nullable=true` instead of `nullable=false`

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to PySpark and am facing a strange problem. I'm trying to set some column to non-nullable while loading a CSV dataset. I can reproduce my case with a very small dataset (`test.csv`):

```
col1,col2,col3
11,12,13
21,22,23
31,32,33
41,42,43
51,,53
```

There is a null value at row 5, column 2 and I don't want to get that row inside my DF. I set all fields as non-nullable (`nullable=false`) but I get a schema with all the three columns having `nullable=true`. This happens even if I set all the three columns as non-nullable! I'm running the latest available version of Spark, 2.0.1.

Here's the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

struct = StructType([   StructField("col1", StringType(), False), \
                        StructField("col2", StringType(), False), \
                        StructField("col3", StringType(), False) \
                    ])

df = spark.read.load("test.csv", schema=struct, format="csv", header="true")
```

`df.printSchema()` returns:

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
```

and `df.show()` returns:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|  11|  12|  13|
|  21|  22|  23|
|  31|  32|  33|
|  41|  42|  43|
|  51|null|  53|
+----+----+----+
```

while I expect this:

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = false)

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|  11|  12|  13|
|  21|  22|  23|
|  31|  32|  33|
|  41|  42|  43|
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: I don't think this issue has been fixed completely as per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10848

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Spark behavior (switch from `False` to `True` here is confusing there is nothing fundamentally wrong going on here. `nullable` argument is not a constraint but a reflection of the source and type semantics which enables certain types of optimization

You state that you want to avoid null values in your data. For this you should use `na.drop` method.

```
df.na.drop()
```

For other ways of handling nulls please take a look at the [`DataFrameNaFunctions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions) (exposed using `DataFrame.na` property) documentation.

CSV format doesn't provide any tools which allow you to specify data constraints so by definition reader cannot assume that input is not null and your data indeed contains nulls.

Comment: Is this not something that should be considered a bug? How can you set something to be false specifically, but internally is changed to true. This even happens to dataframes that do not contain any null values to begin with.

Comment: I agree with @Joop . DataFrame does not perform as we expected(that is if I explicitly request False, I do want to have nullable = false).  Is this still a thing in Spark and not fixed yet ?  I browser around Spark source code but did not see anywhere address this issue. Am I missing a fix ?

Comment: I agree this design decision is counter-intuitive. If I explicitly set a field to be non-nullable in my schema, I would expect the data complies with this schema restriction and if I set option 'FAILFAST' when loading data, the program should throw an exception when a non-nuallbe field has null value.

Comment: "why don't you just drop all na data?"...horrible suggestion, how can this be upvoted at all?

Comment: @Sauron Upvoted for the explanation, not for the suggestion to drop NA.

Comment: I am facing the same problem and wanted to push data to Iceberg from Spark Dataframe. No good solution found till now