# Force spark.read() with inferSchema=True to set numeric columns non-nullable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nullable

After I read a file (using Spark 2.0) with the schema inferred:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('foo').getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv('myData.csv', inferSchema=True)
```

all the columns,`string`and numeric, are nullable.

However if I read the file using an explicit schema, only the`string`columns are nullable.

Is there an way to force `read()` with`inferSchema=True`to set nullability the same way as with an explicit schema?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot force `read()` to set `nullable` to false when you use `inferSchema`. The [source code](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/util/InferSchema.scala) contains this line:

> StructField(thisHeader, dType, nullable = true)

Which explicitly  sets each column's `nullable` to true when using `inferSchema`.

Hence, `nullable` cannot be changed this way, the only way to do it is by specifying the schema yourself or change the schema on the dataframe obtained by using `inferSchema`.

---

However, whether `nullable` is true or false often does not matter to the user. From the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917075/pyspark-structfield-false-always-returns-nullable-true-instead-of); "`nullable` argument is not a constraint but a reflection of the source and type semantics which enables certain types of optimization".

If you want to avoid `null` values in your data you can use `df.dropna()` or `df.fillna()`.