# Configure Glue catalog with not null constraint

Tags: hive, hiveql, aws-glue

I would like to set not null constraint for tables in Glue catalog (refering S3).
But, I can't find any properties related with the constraint in Glue management console.

Is that possible to configure it for Glue table ? I guess Glue table is just a Hive table, so it might be possible.

**EDIT**

- Add description to indicate it's for catalog of S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through <strike>athena or</strike>  glue job code.
Through console, it is not possible.

Comment: It seems athena's CREATE ddl doesn't support constraint statement, is there any document ?

Comment: Yes, Athena being on PRESTO platform, doesn't support  constraint statement for S3 data.

Comment: Hi, I don't get the meaning of doing (not null constraint) through Glue job code. Would you please explain in detail ?

Comment: You can use df.na.drop() which will drop all null fields.

Comment: You can use `df.na.drop()` which will drop all null fields.

You can also try `StructField(thisHeader, dType, nullable = false)` but From the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917075/pyspark-structfield-false-always-returns-nullable-true-instead-of); "nullable argument is not a constraint but a reflection of the source and type semantics which enables certain types of optimization".

Comment: I got it. So far, we can't eliminate null value on defining table. But, can do after querying with dataframe.