# PySpark Mark a Column Nullable: false

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a structured stream reading from Kafka and am trying to convert the JSON payload using a Struct schema.

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "metadata": {},
            "name": "test",
            "nullable": true,
            "type": {
                "containsNull": true,
                "elementType": {
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "metadata": {},
                            "name": "message",
                            "nullable": false,
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "metadata": {},
                            "name": "recipient_id",
                            "nullable": true,
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "struct"
                },
                "type": "array"
            }
        },
        {
            "metadata": {},
            "name": "user_id",
            "nullable": true,
            "type": "long"
        }
    ],
    "type": "struct"
}
```

Converting the json schema to Struct by results in the following.

> StructType.fromJson(jsonSchema)

```
StructType([StructField('test', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('message', StringType(), False), StructField('recipient_id', LongType(), True)]), True), True), StructField('user_id', LongType(), True)])
```

Converting the payload using this schema results in a data frame schema where the nullable is set to true even though it is set to false in the above schema and passing the null value to the field is not resulting in any errors.

```
spark_df = spark_df.selectExpr('timestamp', "CAST(value AS STRING)")
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn("value",from_json(col("value"),schemaNew, {"mode": "FAILFAST"}))
spark_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- test: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- message: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- recipient_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_id: long (nullable = true)
```

How else can we read the schema from a file and apply nullable property and convert the JSON data to proper dataframe?

Comment: There's a description here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917075/pyspark-structfield-false-always-returns-nullable-true-instead-of Although it does not seem to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since `from_json()` ignores nullability information (see explanation below), you could try add a `filter()` right after that will drop such data (where `message` is `null`). Or you could try to use `createDataFrame()` which checks for nullability and merge back if that's an option.

**Why `from_json()` ignores nullability info**

Prior to spark 2.3.1, this was happening unexpectedly due to the Jackson parsers producing null regardless of the nullability. There were 2 options to resolve this (from [this SPARK issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23173)):

1. Ignore nullability information in the schema, and assume all fields are nullable. Hence keeping the same behaviour as before due to the limitation of Jackson parsers.
2. Validate the data, and fail during execution if the data has `null`.

They went with option 1 because it's "the more performant option and a lot easier to do" and "less invasive" too. Hence, **`from_json()` ignores nullability information** set in the schema.