# databricks spark allowing null value in column even if schema is nullable false

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

i have following schema

```
json_schema_string = "{\"fields\":[{\"metadata\":{},\"name\":\"Name\",\"nullable\":true,\"type\":\"string\"},{\"metadata\":{},\"name\":\"empid\",\"nullable\":false,\"type\":\"integer\"},{\"metadata\":{},\"name\":\"age\",\"nullable\":false,\"type\":\"integer\"},{\"metadata\":{},\"name\":\"ph_number\",\"nullable\":true,\"type\":\"long\"},{\"metadata\":{},\"name\":\"address\",\"nullable\":true,\"type\":\"string\"}],\"type\":\"struct\"}"
```

which gets converted to

```
StructType([StructField('Name', StringType(), True), StructField('empid', IntegerType(), False), StructField('age', IntegerType(), False), StructField('ph_number', LongType(), True), StructField('address', StringType(), True)])
```

i am running following code =>

```
   df_current = spark.read\
.option("header","true")\
.schema(json_schema)\
.option("inferSchema","false")\
.option("badRecordsPath", f"{bad_records_path_session}/{STEP_NAME}") \
.option("multiLine", "true")\
.option('escape', "\"")\
.option('delimiter', ',')\
.option("encoding", "UTF-8")\
.csv(file_path)\
.selectExpr("*", "lower(_metadata.file_name) as pmd_file_path", "_metadata.file_modification_time as pmd_file_mod_DTM", f"{time_of_run} as pmd_batch_id")

##df_current.write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable(f"{catalog_name}.dnu_development.test_reject_records")
df_current.show()
```

but when i print **df_current.show()**, i can see Null in the field and hence row is missing from => **reject_file_loc** (refer screenshot)

[image]

Comment: The null values in the df_current DataFrame indicates that there are missing or invalid values in the input CSV file that could not be parsed according to the specified schema. Perhaps, the age column in input has a string value which is not accepted as it is of integer type. The badRecordsPath option that you're using should write these records to a separate file in JSON format, which you can use to diagnose and fix the issues with the input data.

Comment: You can use ` .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")` to drop those rows

Comment: @Aswin i cannot use DROPMALFORMED and badRecordsPath together. i do not want to drop it, i want to record it.

Comment: @Aswin  i am providing csv, and i am making sure that age is blank. so it is not malformed, but null in input. and i marking this field as "nullable" false. so ideally DF should not hold this value, else what is a use of nullable attribute in Spark schema?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark: StructField(..., ..., False) always returns \`nullable=true\` instead of \`nullable=false\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917075/pyspark-structfield-false-always-returns-nullable-true-instead-of)

Answer (score 0):

The ***nullable*** attribute in the Spark schema is used to specify whether a column allows null values or not.

In your code, you have defined the age column with ***nullable=False***, which means that the column should not contain null values.

It's important to note that the nullable attribute in the schema is primarily used for enforcing the schema during read operations and for optimizing data processing.
When you define a column as nullable=False, Spark ensures that the column values adhere to the specified data type and do not contain null values during the schema inference or when applying the schema explicitly.

In your case, if you have a CSV file where the age column has blank values, they will be treated as empty strings or as non-null values
The column will not be filtered out based on null checks alone because empty strings are considered non-null values.

If you want to treat empty strings as null values and filter them out based on null checks

In your case You can use the below code:

```
df_null = df_current.filter(col("Name").isNull() |
                            col("empid").isNull() |
                            col("age").isNull() |
                            (col("age") == "") |
                            col("ph_number").isNull() |
                            col("address").isNull())
```

By adding (col("age") == "") to the filter condition, it checks for both null and empty string values, effectively filtering out rows where the age column is either null or empty.
This ensures that the DataFrame holds only the records with non-null and non-empty string values for the age column.
(OR)
Also I have tried a approach where you can write filtering the  NULL values and writing them to a path.

- Achiving the NON NULL Values along with the recording the NULL Values
  with the help of providing the file path and output paths
- These below Path specify the file path   for the input CSV file (file_path)and the output paths for saving the DataFrames with null records (output_path_null) and non-null records (output_path_non_null).

  file_path="/FileStore/tables/Convertedjson.csv"
  output_path_null =
  "/FileStore/tables/null_records"
  output_path_non_null = "/FileStore/tables/non_null_records"

**Here is the below code:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
        from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,
        StructField, StringType, IntegerType,  LongType
        from pyspark.sql.functions import col
        spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
        Converted_json_schema = StructType([
        StructField('Name', StringType(), True),
        StructField('empid', IntegerType(), False),
        StructField('age', IntegerType(), False),
        StructField('ph_number', LongType(), True),
        StructField('address', StringType(), True)
        ])
        file_path = "/FileStore/tables/Convertedjson.csv"
        output_path_null = "/FileStore/tables/null_records"
        output_path_non_null = "/FileStore/tables/non_null_records"
        df_current = spark.read \
        .option("header", "true") \
        .schema(Converted_json_schema) \
        .option("inferSchema", "false") \
        .option("multiLine", "true") \
        .option('escape', "\"") \
        .option('delimiter', ',') \
        .option("encoding", "UTF-8") \
        .csv(file_path)
        **Filter DataFrame for null records**
        df_null = df_current.filter(col("Name").isNull() |
        col("empid").isNull() |
        col("age").isNull() |
        col("ph_number").isNull() |
        col("address").isNull())
        df_null.show()
        **Save the DataFrame with null records to a specific location (overwrite if it already exists)**
        df_null.write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").csv(output_path_null)
        **Filter DataFrame for non-null records**
        df_non_null = df_current.filter(col("Name").isNotNull() &
        col("empid").isNotNull() &
        col("age").isNotNull() &
        col("ph_number").isNotNull() &
        col("address").isNotNull())
        df_non_null.show()
        **Save the DataFrame with non-null records to a specific location (overwrite if it already exists)**
        df_non_null.write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").csv(output_path_non_null)
```

**Filtering the DataFrame for null records:**

- From the above code filters the df_current DataFrame using the filter function and checks
  for null values in each column using isNull function.
- Rows where any of the specified columns have a null value are
  retained. The resulting DataFrame, containing only the null records,
  is stored in df_null, and then it is displayed using show().

**Saving the DataFrame with null records to a specific location:**   `df_null.write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").csv(output_path_null)`
This code saves the ***df_null*** DataFrame as CSV

[image]